# Destroy entity in Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

How can I destroy an entity after some action is performed in Sidekiq's worker?

I have following code which doesn't work (mail is not deleted):

```
class MailingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Workerdef

  def perform(mail_id)
     mail = Mail.find mail_id
     #some logic for sending email
     mail.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted correct code? It should be `def perform(mail_id)` not `perform(mail_id)`.

Comment: My mistake, corrected. But that's not the problem.

Comment: Any callbacks in the Mail model?

Comment: This should work, a validation may be preventing the delete. What happens if you use `delete` instad of `destroy` (skips callbacks)?

Comment: Still doesn't work, I tried both (delete, destroy). There is no callback in Mail model.

Comment: What do you have in your sidekiq logs?
Try `Rails.logger.debug mail.inspect` within your perform method, before and after calling `destroy`.

Let's see what it shows.

Comment: Restarting server helped (don't know why). It's finally working.

Comment: @kmaci this is expected when working with sidekiq. The code is only re-loaded when you restart the server.